# how to build "mongos" server in mongodb for sharding?

Tags: mongodb, sharding

I have searched "how to build a mongos server in mongodb" because I am building a simple sharding system locally. No I want to use the "addShard" function. It seems it would be the easiest if I choose "mongos".

Comment: Did you check [Deploy a Sharded Cluster](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/deploy-shard-cluster/)? This one may also help: https://github.com/Wernfried/mongoDB-oneclick

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit thx for your reply. I finished the set up after reading your mentioned information!